# Responsive page with Bootstrap

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap, zend-framework, responsive-design

I have the page below and I am trying to make it responsive with Bootstrap.
First column has some text, second column has a form.
Can you help me understand  why when I scale my browser it is not working?

```
<div class="container-fluid">
   <h1 class="title-2 title-3"><span style="font-size: 36px; line-height: 40px;">TITLE1</span></h1>
      <div class="row">
         <div class="col-sm-6">
            <ul>
             <li>Text1</li>
             <li>Text2</li>
             <li>Text3</li>
            </ul>
         </div>   

<div class="col-sm-6">
   <div class="row">
      <div class="grid_6">
              <?php echo $form->getElement("first_name")?>
       </div>
      <div class="grid_6">
                <?php echo $form->getElement("last_name")?>
       </div>
    </div>
                //form 
    <div class="row submit">
                <?php echo $form->getElement("post_now")?>
    </div>
```

Comment: I think you forgot to ask a specific question.

Comment: I edited with a question

Answer (score 1):

Outside of adding a link the following to your `<head>` it looks like it works just fine:

`<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">`

**UPDATE** 
Now that we know that's in there, try updating your code to this. I updated your class tags to `.col-md-6` and closed a few of your other tags. Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jdcutter/mtb836jd/1/) to see the non-single column.

```html
<div class="container">
<h1 class="title-2 title-3"><span style="font-size: 36px; line-height: 40px;">TITLE1</span></h1>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
      <ul>
        <li>Text1</li>
        <li>Text2</li>
        <li>Text3</li>
      </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
  
     <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
          <?php echo $form->getElement("first_name")?>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
          <?php echo $form->getElement("last_name")?>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
          <?php echo $form->getElement("post_now")?>
      </div>
    </div>
  
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It is added in the head sorry I didn't include it in my paste. it's not working :(

Comment: Just to clear up a thought. Is it working when you scale your browser but not on your phone?